# How do I center text next to a floating image using css?

Tags: css, html, image

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            img{
                float: left;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="img" src="imgsource.jpg">
        <h2> Text that should be next to the image. </h2>
        <p> Text that should be below the image and heading. </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that the text next to the image isn't centered and the next paragraph also goes next to the image when I would like it below the image and heading.

Comment: Can you make a quick sketch of what layout are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dxbbog2k/

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px
}

h2{
    display: inline;
}

p{
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/kitten/kitten-3.jpg">
<h2> Text that should be next to the image. </h2>

<p>Text that should be below the image and heading.</p>
```

Comment: Don't you want display:inline on the h2?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you should change your HTML structure a bit first:

```
<img id="img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
<div id="text">
    <h2> Text that should be next to the image. </h2>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p> Text that should be below the image and heading. </p>
```

Then use floats on the correct elements to position them next to eachother:

```
img, #text{
    float: left;
}
```

Using `display: table-cell` and `vertical align` you can vertically center your text next to the image. *Note: you must know your image height for this.*

```
#text h2{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Finally, don't forget to [clear your floats](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) so the rest of your text appears **below** the image.

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vwrfL5Ly/1/)